# Hitting time of an Ornstein-Ulhenbeck process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

If we consider a nice Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
$d x (t) = - \gamma x(t) \,dt + \sigma \,d w (t)$
with $x(0) = x_0 \in (-L,L)$.
Here $\gamma, \sigma$ are positive constants and $w(t)$ is a Wiener process.

Is the law of $\tau = \inf \{ t>0, |x(t)| = L \}$ the first hitting time of $\pm L$ by $x(t)$ known explicitly when $x_0 \neq 0$? When $x_0 = 0$, it is not a big issue.

Sorry if the solution is straightforward but it isn't clear to me.

Comment: I don't know the first reference, but this is known. Look up the first passage time of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Comment: For example, see these notes: http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/ou.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for the two comments. I will go through these notes and be back soon. m.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that finding its density is still open as mentioned here: [On the First Hitting Time Density of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.02390.pdf)

The Laplace transform has been computed though as mentioned there too.